# React apollo client api calling two time

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

This is my React code of ApolloClient

```
function EmpTable() {      
  const GET_EMPLOYEE = gql`
    query refetch($id: String) {
      employeeById(id: $id) {
        id
        name
        role
      }
    }
  `;

  const {refetch} = useQuery(GET_EMPLOYEE)

  const getEmpByID = (id) => {
    refetch({
      id: id
    }).then((response) => {
      // do something
    })
    
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      {/* { I am rending list of employee with map and passing id this way
         <a onClick={() => getEmpByID(id)}>get employ info</a>
      } */}    
    </div>
  );
}

export default EmpTable;
```

Everything is working very well in this code, the only problem is the API being called two times, first time it returns no data, and 2nd time, it returns the expected data.

How can I prevent calling this twice?

I guess this is executing first time: `const {refetch} = useQuery(GET_EMPLOYEE)` and making the first request without data, because, no variable is passed there. I know I can can pass a variable in `useQuery` first time but the problem is that I can’t pass this from there, because the query params are not in my state or props.

Can anyone tell me what is the possible solution for this?

Comment: `useLazyQuery`?

Comment: is useLazyQuery has promise method?

Comment: It is not working instead if is firing me error

Comment: how used? read docs

Answer (score 1):

Due to documentantion:

> When React mounts and renders a component that calls the useQuery
> hook, Apollo Client automatically executes the specified query. But
> what if you want to execute a query in response to a different event,
> such as a user clicking a button? The useLazyQuery hook is perfect for
> executing queries in response to events other than component
> rendering. This hook acts just like useQuery, with one key exception:
> when useLazyQuery is called, it does not immediately execute its
> associated query. Instead, it returns a function in its result tuple
> that you can call whenever you're ready to execute the query:

Example :

```
const GET_COUNTRIES = gql`
  {
    countries {
      code
      name
    }
  }
`;
export function DelayedCountries() {
  const [getCountries, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_COUNTRIES);
  if (loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>;

  if (data && data.countries) {
    console.log(data.countries);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => getCountries()}>
        Click me to print all countries!
      </button>
      {data &&
        data.countries &&
        data.countries.map((c, i) => <div key={i}>{c.name}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`useLazyQuery` will be executed at the moment, when getCountries is called.

https://codesandbox.io/s/apollo-client-uselazyquery-example-6ui35?file=/src/Countries.js

Comment: different use case ... OP wants to prevnt first querying (when no arg/variable known) - bad refresh usage, bad data handling, etc  ... useLazyQuery should be used (with passing variable like onClick mutation)

Comment: Thanks @PiotrŻak but what is the call back fuction in useLazyQuery, i didnt see anything like this apollo client docs. can you please specify the call back fuction name or how i can use promise there

Comment: @howrecepes i found solution on internet and just explaining in edited comments :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior in React 18, all events are called twice, this is new in React 18, and, **only happens in development**.

Now, why are they doing this? because it helps to identify bugged effects and hooks, and it works.

If you wanna disable this you can do it by disabling **strict mode** (https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

So, if the component is working, you have no warning about data leaking stay calm and continue. Another option to try is compile your application and run it in production mode, if the hook it's called twice then yeah, by all means, validate your component code (and it's parent components)